# How can I select a new row when I right click?

Tags: java, swing

I'm programming a database logger program. After the user clicks on a new row, I want to point to that row. In this way, user will can understand which in row when that opens pop-up menu with right-click.

This is my program's GUI:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvXK4.png]

I tried below codes:

```
tbl_patika_list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                Point point = e.getPoint();
                int clickedRow = tbl_patika_list.rowAtPoint(point);
                tbl_patika_list.clearSelection();
                tbl_patika_list.setRowSelectionInterval(clickedRow,clickedRow);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Add a mention and a tag for the GUI framework. Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Vaadin?

Comment: I added as a tag.

Comment: `if (javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> opens pop-up menu with right-click.

The old way is to use a MouseListener to show the popup.

The newer way is to use the `setComponentPopup(...)` method:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TableRightClick extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    JPopupMenu popup;

    public TableRightClick()
    {
        popup = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Click Me");
        menuItem.addActionListener( this );
        popup.add( menuItem );

        JTable table = new JTable(10, 5);
        table.setComponentPopupMenu( popup );
        popup.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
            {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
                {
                    Point point = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(popup, new Point(0, 0), table);
                    int currentRow = table.rowAtPoint(point);
                    int currentColumn = table.columnAtPoint(point);
                    table.changeSelection(currentRow, currentColumn, false, false);
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {}

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {}
        });
/*
        //  When using a MouseListener to show popup menu
        table.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (e.isPopupTrigger())
                {
                    JTable source = (JTable)e.getSource();
                    int row = source.rowAtPoint( e.getPoint() );
                    int column = source.columnAtPoint( e.getPoint() );

                    source.changeSelection(row, column, false, false);

                    popup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });
*/

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        add( new JScrollPane(table) );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Component c = (Component)e.getSource();
        JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu)c.getParent();
        JTable table = (JTable)popup.getInvoker();
        System.out.println(table.getSelectedRow() + " : " + table.getSelectedColumn());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Right Click");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TableRightClick());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```